# will php handle session automatically if cookies are disabled?

Tags: php, session

If cookies are disabled then session works in following two ways:

1. Form hidden input tag as session id
2. session id is appended in url

But will the above two ways works automatically i.e will PHP handle it automatically? or we will have to  manually set them?
If PHP does it automatically then how ?

Comment: If you can have it run client side you should check local storage

Comment: Thanks .But my question above two methods will be handled by PHP or I will have to manually do it?

Comment: check this Question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6012021/session-data-not-showing-when-cookies-disabled

Comment: if some one disables cookies, they should be banned from the internet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't have to set this manually PHP handle this for you
It uses the cookies if available, or else it switch to send it via a url,
provided that `session.use_trans_sid` is enabled

```
ini_set("session.use_trans_sid", 1);
```

Notice that URL based session management has additional security [risks](http://php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.use-trans-sid)
and see this [link](http://php.net/manual/en/session.idpassing.php) for more infos

Comment: Thanks for reply.May I know how it handles? any idea about it?

Comment: @Swati, yes, see the edited answer for more infos

Comment: Hey Thank you so much for detailed explaination